# akka fsm matchEvent implemantation

Tags: java, events, akka, fsm

I'm trying to understand AKKA fsm "matchEvent" :

```
public final <ET> FSMStateFunctionBuilder<S, D> matchEvent(Class<ET> eventType, TypedPredicate2<ET, D> predicate, Apply2<ET, D, State<S, D>> apply) {
        return (new FSMStateFunctionBuilder()).event(eventType, predicate, apply);
    }
```

after looking in http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.3.4/index.html?akka/actor/AbstractFSM.html
this what I found:

```
public <P> FSMStateFunctionBuilder<S,D> event(java.lang.Class<P> eventType,
                                              FI.TypedPredicate2<P,D> predicate,
                                              FI.Apply2<P,D,FSM.State<S,D>> apply)
```

> Add a case statement that matches if the event type and predicate
>   matches. Parameters: eventType - the event type to match on predicate
>   - a predicate that will be evaluated on the data and the event apply - an action to apply to the event and state data if there is a match
>   Returns: the builder with the case statement added

Can someone tell me please how does the match of the events is implemented?

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/lambda-fsm.html or http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/fsm.html depending whether you can use Java8 or not.
BTW, akka is now in 2.4, any reason why you check the 2.3 API?

Comment: I'm using JAVA 8.. I'm using the latest api, no reason why the link is 2.3

Comment: Then you have a nice example at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/lambda-fsm.html#A_Simple_Example

Here you have a nice example on how to implement Akka FSM in Java8

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from the docs [simple example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/lambda-fsm.html#A_Simple_Example):

```
...
public class Buncher extends AbstractFSM<State, Data> {
{
  startWith(Idle, Uninitialized);

  when(Idle,
    matchEvent(SetTarget.class, Uninitialized.class,
      (setTarget, uninitialized) ->
        stay().using(new Todo(setTarget.getRef(), new LinkedList<>()))));

  // transition elided ...

  when(Active, Duration.create(1, "second"),
    matchEvent(Arrays.asList(Flush.class, StateTimeout()), Todo.class,
      (event, todo) -> goTo(Idle).using(todo.copy(new LinkedList<>()))));

  // unhandled elided ...

  initialize();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to express a guard condition based on incoming event field, or data (or a combination), use something like...:

```
when(Active, Duration.create(1, "second"),
    matchEvent(Arrays.asList(Flush.class, StateTimeout()), Todo.class,
      (event, todo) -> todo.getQueue != null //any logical condition using event or data, 

      (event, todo) -> goTo(Idle).using(todo.copy(new LinkedList<>()))));
```